# Show User's IP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ip

I'm having trouble showing the user's IP in wordpress, I tried to do it with the simple PHP code `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

And even some that I found here, and it always returns ":: 1"

I tried this code below too and it didn't work

```
public function getIpAddress() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ips = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
        return trim($ips[count($ips) - 1]);
    } else {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}
```

Then I installed 2 plugins to test and with them gives the same result. Now I was wondering if it may be a question of my network or if Wordpress blocks the user's IP.

On the main page I need to return the user's IP so that he can find it more easily.

Comment: Done, please, help me with this problem, I didn't see it was in English and it was closed before I could correct it

Comment: It's all good Lucas, your question has been reopened.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the return was because I used localhost, so the ::1 is an response indicating that, the same code in a better worked network returns the expected value.